# how does isNan( ) work?

Tags: objective-c, c, nan, math.h

isNan is defined like this in iOS SDK, math.h as below,

```
#define isnan(x)                                                         \
    ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_isnanf((float)(x))          \
    : sizeof(x) == sizeof(double) ? __inline_isnand((double)(x))         \
                                  : __inline_isnanl((long double)(x)))
```

And the inline function goes like this,

```
__header_always_inline int __inline_isnanf(float __x) {
    return __x != __x;
}
```

__header_always_inline is just to force the compiler to make the function surely inline.

What actually has been done in the inline function is pretty evasive to my eyes.

```
return __x != __x;
```

What does this line do? How does it verify if the argument is a NaN or not?

**Edit:**

The question here is **NOT** why NaN is not equal to NaN; but how its implemented. So please guide your answers towards the actual low level implementation.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE 754 NaN values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1565164)

Comment: "but how its implemented" -- I don't think you understand the question you're asking. Arithmetic on NaNs (and other floating point) is implemented in the microcode of your computer. Comparing a NaN to a NaN yields not equal ... because it does; because it's specified to. How is that implemented? By yielding not equal whenever NaNs are compared. There really isn't anything else to say about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CF http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

> A comparison with a NaN always returns an unordered result even when comparing with itself.

Mean a NaN is ALWAYS different from what you compare it too :)

I suppose the compiler/CPU has their own way to check for this special value, maybe someone can give a better answer than me about the implementation...

Comment: And importantly, any number other than NaN is equal to itself. Yes, the FPU will just implement the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: "compiler/CPU has their own way to check for this special value" -- of course there is a way: the bit configurations for NaNs are well defined. But the compiler doesn't care; it's all done in the microcode of the floating point unit.

Comment: @JimBalter  it's all done in the microcode ... Is this statement valid for every architecture ?